# How to set Google API response to json

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-contacts-api

I am using Google Contact API which sends contact details in XML format, Is there any way to get the same response in JSON format.

My request URL :

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?format=json
```

This is how I am trying now but its not working even after adding format=json I am getting XML rewsponse.

Answer (score 4):

to get json response we have to use alt instead of format

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?**alt**=json